# Hoy to get the full size of an imageview image?

Tags: android, imageview

I have displayed an image in a imageview control, but when I try to send the image to a remote server, a php server, the image stored in the server is a minimized version no the full size image captured in the imageview control.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE URI FROM THE BITMAP
            Uri tempUri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), imagen);
            imagepath = getRealPathFromURI(tempUri);
          Log.i("uploadFile", "File Path : "
                    + imagepath);
            // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE ACTUAL PATH
            //File finalFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(tempUri));

            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(DisplayImgCamActivity.this, "", "Subiendo imagen...", true);
             //messageText.setText("uploading started.....");
             new Thread(new Runnable() {
                 public void run() {
                      uploadFile(imagepath);           
                 }
               }).start();              
        }

public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {        
    String fileName = sourceFileUri;

    //Log.i("uploadFile", "File Uri : "
      //      + fileName);


    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;  
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 
    File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri); 

    if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

         dialog.dismiss(); 

         Log.e("SubirImagen", "No existe la imagen :" + imagepath);

         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                 //messageText.setText("Source File not exist :"+ imagepath);
                 Toast.makeText(DisplayImgCamActivity.this, "No existe imagen a subir", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }
         }); 

         return 0;

    }
    else
    {
         try { 

               // open a URL connection to the Servlet
             FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
             URL url = new URL(urlServer);

             // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
             conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
             conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
             conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
             conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
             conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
             conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
             conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
             conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
             conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName); 

             dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

             dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
             dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                                       + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

             dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

             // create a buffer of  maximum size
             bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 

             bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
             buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

             // read file and write it into form...
             bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

             while (bytesRead > 0) {

               dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
               bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
               bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
               bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);   

              }

             // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
             dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
             dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

             // Responses from the server (code and message)
             serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
             String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

             Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                     + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

             if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                      public void run() {
                          String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                                +" F:/wamp/wamp/www/uploads";
                          //messageText.setText(msg);
                          Toast.makeText(DisplayImgCamActivity.this, "Imagen subida satisfactoriamente", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                      }
                  });                
             }    

             //close the streams //
             fileInputStream.close();
             dos.flush();
             dos.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

            dialog.dismiss();  
            ex.printStackTrace();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    //messageText.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                    Toast.makeText(DisplayImgCamActivity.this, "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

            Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);  
        } catch (Exception e) {

            dialog.dismiss();  
            e.printStackTrace();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    //messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                    Toast.makeText(DisplayImgCamActivity.this, "Error: ver logcat ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
            Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : "  + e.getMessage(), e);  
        }
        dialog.dismiss();       
        return serverResponseCode; 

     } // End else block 
   }    

public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    String path = Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}

public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null); 
    cursor.moveToFirst(); 
    int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA); 
    return cursor.getString(idx); 
}
```

Comment: Please provide us some code, what do you have so far?

Comment: I added some code to my question. Look at that.

Answer (score 0):

do not know if I understand the question, but what happens is you send an image that is loaded in imageview and is the recives a php which happens to be less size than what was shown in the imageview, if so the same is the image you have in the app is small, what happens is that the same is scaled imageview not if you can help with the solution, sorry for my English

edit: what I mean is that the look of the images byte aver if the same without any modification in both

Comment: Yes, i capture an image with the camera And put it in an imageview. When i send the image of the imageview to the php server the image sent is smaller than the one of the imageview. The image captured with the camera when i see it in the image gallery has a full size

Comment: I think the image that is sent must be the same as the is receiving, try taking the photo and save it to device to do with how many byte guard and then compared with the php is just an idea

Comment: The imageview has width And height size. Could it be the problem?

Comment: ahh could be that when the image is being passed to imageview but to send you the're taking from what it looks like in the image view is smaller, try to keep it on the device and send it from the saved file something is code would be good to see Edit: Like this resolution that is taking the photo showing the imageview try to save the picture and send from this stored aver if you send the same resolution that captures

Comment: I thought that the image displayed in the imageview had the same size as it stored in the smartphone when captured with the camera.

Comment: eh I looked at your code, I have a question, why not you try to send an image that was captured by the camera, to rule out this problem in the atra capture instead of the camera aver if still gives the same error, by the way you speak Spanish because in your code the I speak Spanish if you want to communicate better appears you would pass my email

Answer (score 0):

Well, at last i could end the script. Finally i chose the full path where the image is stored in the smartphone instead of the image displayed in the imageview. In this case, i can get the full image that is what i wanted. The image displayed in a imageview is a minimized version of the image stored in the phone.